# C# - WPF ComboBox not setting default value in Code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf

Following code of my `WPF` app is showing the default value as blank instead of `CA`. I've tested in debug mode that the `cmbStates.SelectedValue` is showing `NULL` after I move to the next line while using `F11` in `VS2017`. I've tried moving the code to Windows loaded event but still the exact same behavior.

**Note**:

1. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3391259/1232087) post it should work, but it's not. Maybe, my case is a bit different
2. The code successfully displays the `comboBox` values but the top of the comboBox is blank unless I manually select a particular value for the comboBox.

**Question**: What I may be missing here and how can we make it work?

**XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
....
....
>
 <Grid>
....
....
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbStates" IsEditable="True" SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectionChanged="cmbStates_SelectionChanged" />
....
....

  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind for MainWindow**:

```
....
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    cmbStates.ItemsSource = new List<string>() {"OH", "VA", "CA", "TN", "CA", "DE"};
    cmbStates.SelectedValue =  "CA";
}
....
```

**UPDATE**:

Please note that the question is more specific to setting the default value in `Code Behind` and not in `XAML` because the list is quite longer than shown in this post (for brevity), and that the default value is not always "CA" - it varies based on the business requirements. You can think of "CA" as some string variable value instead, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Try `SelectedItem`... `SelectedValue` has another use case. See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2006/11/07/combobox-selecteditem-selectedvalue-selectedwhat/

Comment: @GlennFerrie I had already tried `SelectedItem` but that also returns `NULL`.

Comment: Remove SelectedValuePath="Content" in your combobox..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you set the `ItemsSource` of your `ComboBox` to a `List<string>`, you should set the `SelectedItem` property to a `string` that is included in this list and remove `SelectedValuePath="Content"` from your XAML as a `string` has no `Content` property:

```
cmbStates.ItemsSource = new List<string>() {"OH", "VA", "CA", "TN", "CA", "DE"};
cmbStates.SelectedItem =  "CA";
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbStates" IsEditable="True" SelectionChanged="cmbStates_SelectionChanged" />
```

Comment: Sorry for marking it late as an `Answer`. It works for strings (+1 my upvote, as well). It does not however work for a list of `double`. E.g., following code does not set the default value of combobox to 9: `cmbFontSize.ItemsSource = new List<double>() { 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 36, 48, 72 };
 cmbFontSize.SelectedItem = 9;`

Answer (score 0):

The issue why the selected item is not displayed is this `xml` attribute:

```
SelectedValuePath="Content"
```

While the `SelectedValue` is set to "CA", it is not displayed, because you advised your view to check for the property **Content** for the `SelectedItem`, which of course is not present for the `string` that you use.

In order to make it work for your above example, you would simply remove that attribute within your combobox.

On the other hand, if your bound items are classes and you would need one field to display and another one as the value / identifier, the `SelectedValuePath` would make sense, in combination with the `DisplayMemberPath` attribute.

Let's say your items would look something like this:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public SomeModel(string abbreviation, string content)
    {
        Abbreviation = abbreviation;
        Content = content;
    }
}
```

In this case the `ComboBox` would look like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbStates" IsEditable="True" SelectedValuePath="Abbreviation" DisplayMemberPath="Content" SelectionChanged="cmbStates_SelectionChanged" />
```

This way the **Abbreviation** property is the actuall value of the `ComboBoxItem` and the **Content** is used as the display for the `ComboBox`. Now your `MainWindow` constructor would look like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    cmbStates.ItemsSource = new List<SomeModel>
    {
        new SomeModel("OH","Ohio"), new SomeModel("VA","Virginia"), new SomeModel("CA","California "),
        new SomeModel("TN","Tennessee"), new SomeModel("DE","Delaware")
    };
    cmbStates.SelectedValue = "CA";
}
```

Besides this case, I would advise yout to look into [WPF data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-wpf) and [WPF MVVM pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish).